# WriteStartElement using an Array value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a XML document using visual basic in visual studio 2010.
it seems its not letting me use array values when i write a start element.

```
arrayValue = array(UBound(array))
Dim xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("xmlfile.xml", xws)
        xw.WriteStartDocument()
        xw.WriteStartElement(arrayValue)
        xw.WriteEndElement()
        xw.WriteEndDocument()
        xw.Flush()
        xw.Close()
```

Wont let me do that it gives me an error and also does nothing.
"A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"

Whats going on?

Comment: Would that make a difference you think? Its in a visual basic windows form.

Comment: What line is the error thrown on? Have you tried checking that arrayValue is not a null value? You could also try xw.WriteStartDocument(True)

Comment: yes sir, i did a debug.writeline(arrayValue) right before the xw.WriteStartElement(arrayValue) line and it returns a line of text. xw.WriteStartDocument(True) gave the same resulters.

Comment: Was xws declared properly? i.e. Dim xws as New XmlWriterSettings()

Comment: VB.NET and VBA are completely different languages and development platforms: they only happen to be syntactically similar. VBA is related to VB.NET in the same way javascript is to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the XMLTextWriter.

```
arrayValue = array(UBound(array))
Dim xWriter As New Xml.XmlTextWriter("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mytest.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
xWriter.Indentation = 2
xWriter.WriteStartDocument(True)
xWriter.WriteStartElement(arrayValue)
xWriter.WriteEndElement()
xWriter.Flush()
xWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few of my arrayValue values were not coming out as xml standard. There happen to be a lot of them.

Some started with numbers (which you cannot have as nodenames). That is why it wasn't writing to the document. I have to write a filter to change the values into XML standard.

I wish visual studio would of told me this in an error message or something. Thanks for all of your help.